# Как пропорционально уменьшить изображение в php

Tags: php

Загрузили на сервер картинку, нужно, сделать к ней превью, в 300 пикселей по ширине.
Какие есть готовые библиотеки, функции? Что почитать, что посоветуете, чтобы написать быстро с малой кровью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Изменение размера изображения php](http://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+php&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос "Как пропорционально уменьшить картинку?": в этом нет ничего сложного, достаточно лишь найти отношение высоты к ширине. Затем установить любую свою уменьшенную ширину, а высота будет равняться установленной ширине, на найденное отношение.