# Вывод уменьшенной картинки с помощью php

Tags: php

Допустим есть картинка 1000 на 1000 пикселей.
Как вывести картинку размером 200 на 100 пикселей с помощью php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как пропорционально уменьшить изображение в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/87859/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используются модули [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) или [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Примеры так же есть в документации

ImageMagick

```
function scaleImage($imagePath) {
    $imagick = new Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $imagick->scaleImage(200, 100, true);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
```

GD

```
function scaleImage($imagePath) {
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
    $scaled = imagescale($src, 200, 100, true);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    imagejpeg($scaled );
    imagedestroy($scaled);
    imagedestroy($src);
}
```

Comment: тем не менее картинку после ресайза лучше сохранить ив следующий раз отдавать сохраненное. Проще всего для данных целей настроить реврайты таким образом чтобы при отсутствии файла управление передавалось в пхп, который и делает вышеописанное.

Comment: @teran, согласен с комментарием.